# RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I have the following PyTorch model:

```
import math
from abc import abstractmethod

import torch.nn as nn


class AlexNet3D(nn.Module):
    @abstractmethod
    def get_head(self):
        pass

    def __init__(self, input_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.features = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(1, 64, kernel_size=(5, 5, 5), stride=(2, 2, 2), padding=0),
            nn.BatchNorm3d(64),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=3, stride=3),

            nn.Conv3d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), stride=(1, 1, 1), padding=0),
            nn.BatchNorm3d(128),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=3, stride=3),

            nn.Conv3d(128, 192, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm3d(192),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),

            nn.Conv3d(192, 192, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm3d(192),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),

            nn.Conv3d(192, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm3d(128),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=3, stride=3),
        )

        self.classifier = self.get_head()

        for m in self.modules():
            if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
                n = m.kernel_size[0] * m.kernel_size[1] * m.out_channels
                m.weight.data.normal_(0, math.sqrt(2. / n))
            elif isinstance(m, nn.BatchNorm3d):
                m.weight.data.fill_(1)
                m.bias.data.zero_()

    def forward(self, x):
        xp = self.features(x)
        x = xp.view(xp.size(0), -1)
        x = self.classifier(x)
        return [x, xp]


class AlexNet3DDropoutRegression(AlexNet3D):
    def get_head(self):
        return nn.Sequential(nn.Dropout(),
                             nn.Linear(self.input_size, 64),
                             nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                             nn.Dropout(),
                             nn.Linear(64, 1),
                             )
```

I am initializing the model like this:

```
def init_model(self):
    model = AlexNet3DDropoutRegression(4608)
    if self.use_cuda:
        log.info("Using CUDA; {} devices.".format(torch.cuda.device_count()))
        if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
            model = nn.DataParallel(model)
        model = model.to(self.device)
    return model
```

After training, I save the model like this:

```
    torch.save(self.model.state_dict(), self.cli_args.model_save_location)
```

I then attempt to load the saved model:

```
import torch
from reprex.models import AlexNet3DDropoutRegression


model_save_location = "/home/feczk001/shared/data/AlexNet/LoesScoring/loes_scoring_01.pt"

model = AlexNet3DDropoutRegression(4608)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_save_location,
                                 map_location='cpu'))
```

But I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for AlexNet3DDropoutRegression:
    Missing key(s) in state_dict: "features.0.weight", "features.0.bias", "features.1.weight", "features.1.bias", "features.1.running_mean", "features.1.running_var", "features.4.weight", "features.4.bias", "features.5.weight", "features.5.bias", "features.5.running_mean", "features.5.running_var", "features.8.weight", "features.8.bias", "features.9.weight", "features.9.bias", "features.9.running_mean", "features.9.running_var", "features.11.weight", "features.11.bias", "features.12.weight", "features.12.bias", "features.12.running_mean", "features.12.running_var", "features.14.weight", "features.14.bias", "features.15.weight", "features.15.bias", "features.15.running_mean", "features.15.running_var", "classifier.1.weight", "classifier.1.bias", "classifier.4.weight", "classifier.4.bias". 
    Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "module.features.0.weight", "module.features.0.bias", "module.features.1.weight", "module.features.1.bias", "module.features.1.running_mean", "module.features.1.running_var", "module.features.1.num_batches_tracked", "module.features.4.weight", "module.features.4.bias", "module.features.5.weight", "module.features.5.bias", "module.features.5.running_mean", "module.features.5.running_var", "module.features.5.num_batches_tracked", "module.features.8.weight", "module.features.8.bias", "module.features.9.weight", "module.features.9.bias", "module.features.9.running_mean", "module.features.9.running_var", "module.features.9.num_batches_tracked", "module.features.11.weight", "module.features.11.bias", "module.features.12.weight", "module.features.12.bias", "module.features.12.running_mean", "module.features.12.running_var", "module.features.12.num_batches_tracked", "module.features.14.weight", "module.features.14.bias", "module.features.15.weight", "module.features.15.bias", "module.features.15.running_mean", "module.features.15.running_var", "module.features.15.num_batches_tracked", "module.classifier.1.weight", "module.classifier.1.bias", "module.classifier.4.weight", "module.classifier.4.bias".
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 7):

The issue is that you train the model using `DataParallel`, and then attempt to reload the model in a non-parallel network. `DataParallel` is a wrapper class that makes the original model (a `torch.nn.module` object) a class attribute of the `DataParallel` object named `module`. This issue is addressed
on [pytorch discuss](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/loading-a-model-state-dict-after-training-the-model-using-nn-dataparallel/118626/2), [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61854165/why-must-use-dataparallel-when-testing) and [github](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/9176) so I won't rehash the details here as well, but you can fix this by either:

1. Saving and loading the model exclusively as a `DataParallel` object, which will likely cease to be effective when you want to use the model for inference, or
2. Save the `DataParallel` object's  `module` `state_dict` instead as such:

   ```
   # save state dict of DataParallel object
   torch.save(model.module.state_dict(), path)


    .... Later
   # reload weights on non-parallel model
   model.load_state_dict(torch.load(path)
   ```

Here's a trivial example:

```
model = AlexNet3DDropoutRegression(4608) # on cpu
model = nn.DataParallel(model)
model = model.to("cuda") # DataParallel object on GPU(s)


torch.save(model.module.state_dict(),"example_path.pt")

del model
model = AlexNet3DDropoutRegression(4608)

ret = model.load_state_dict(torch.load("example_path.pt")) 
print(ret)
```

Output:

```
>>> <All keys successfully matched>
```

3. Alternatively and perhaps more usefully if you already have a saved `state_dict` you need to reload, you can also load the `state_dict` for the `DataParallel` model, remap the key names to exclude "module", and then use the re-keyed `state_dict`. Something like:

```
incompatible_state_dict = torch.load("DataParallel_save_file.pt")
state_dict = {}
for key in incompatible_state_dict():
    state_dict[key.split("module.")[-1]] = incompatible_state_dict[key]

 ret = model.load_state_dict(state_dict)
 print(ret)
```

Output:

```
>>> <All keys successfully matched>
```

Comment: I'm getting a warning of "unexpected argument" for the `map_location` argument of `torch.save()`.

Comment: Try removing that argument and see if it gives you an error. I believe you shouldn't need it.

Comment: I tried removing that argument and I was back in the same situation I was in before.

Comment: I was able to save and load the model weights using your above code and the additional lines listed in this answer. The critical bit is that if your model is wrapped in a `DataParallel` object, you need to use `model.module.state_dict()` to access the parameters, and if not you simply do `model.state_dict()`. So depending on whether you load and save the checkpoint as a single `nn.module` or as a `DataParallel` object, you'll need to use the appropriate attribute to access the model weights.

Answer (score 4):

`nn.DataParallel` is a wrapper class, it adds a "module." prefix to all the keys in the state dictionary. Therefore, you see `module.features` and `module.classifier` in the unexpected keys. To solve this problem, all you need to do is to remove the `module.` prefix when loading the model `state_dict`.

```
model = AlexNet3DDropoutRegression(4608)
model_save_location = "/home/feczk001/shared/data/AlexNet/LoesScoring/loes_scoring_01.pt"

state_dict = torch.load(model_save_location, map_location='cpu')
model.load_state_dict({k.replace("module.", ""): v for k, v in state_dict.items()})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are loading a state dictionary from an already trained DataParallel model and then you create a new one that does not use DataParallel. `module` is already prefixed when using DataParallel and PyTorch. So if you remove the `module` prefix, you will be fine. Unless you want to use DataParallel for the new model initialization as, you are better off just removing the `module` prefix.

This snippet should do it:

```
model = AlexNet3DDropoutRegression(4608)
state_dict = torch.load(model_save_location, map_location='cpu')
new_state_dict = {}
for key in state_dict.keys():
    new_key = key.replace("module.", "")
    new_state_dict[new_key] = state_dict[key]
model.load_state_dict(new_state_dict)
```