# "Size mismatch - weight - bias" error when loading Deep Q Network model for evaluation

Tags: python, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, dqn

I am trying to evaluate the performance of a trained DQN model with the Deep Q Network

`
device = torch.device("cuda") if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device("cpu")

```
class DeepQNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, lr, n_actions, name, input_dims, chkpt_dir):
        super(DeepQNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.checkpoint_dir = chkpt_dir
        self.checkpoint_file = os.path.join(self.checkpoint_dir, name)

    # you may want to play around with this and forward()
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_dims[0], 64)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(64, 64)
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(64, n_actions)

    self.optimizer = optim.RMSprop(self.parameters(), lr=lr)

    self.loss = nn.MSELoss()
    self.device = T.device('cuda:0' if T.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
    self.to(self.device)

# you may want to play around with this
def forward(self, state):
    flat1 = F.relu(self.fc1(state))
    flat2 = F.relu(self.fc2(flat1))
    actions = self.fc3(flat2)
    return actions

def save_checkpoint(self):
    print('... saving checkpoint ...')
    T.save(self.state_dict(), self.checkpoint_file)

def load_checkpoint(self):
    print('... loading checkpoint ...')
    self.load_state_dict(T.load(self.checkpoint_file))`
```

This model is loaded in another file which uses the functions to load it

```
def use_bline(self):
    self.agent = DQNAgent(chkpt_dir="../Models_DQN/model_b_line", algo='DQNAgent', env_name='Scenario1b')
    # needed to get the pytorch checkpoint
    self.agent.load_models()
    self.agent_name = "Bline"
```

And when running the evaluation file,
I get this error

`RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for DeepQNetwork: size mismatch for fc3.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([54, 64]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([41, 64]). size mismatch for fc3.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([54]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([41]).`

**I have saved the trained model and trying to evaluated the same trained model using my Laptops CPU.**

Let me know if you require more information, this may be a simple problem for which I have not been able to find a solution for. Any help or direction will be very (VERY) appreciated.

I tried using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75724281/runtimeerror-errors-in-loading-state-dict) but got the same error

Answer (score 0):

This `Size mismatch` error means that the saved state_dict and the model you use are not coherent. In the example you give, fc3 layer is `nn.Linear(64, 54)` in your checkpoint but `nn.Linear(64, 41)` in the model you created. Since these 2 layers are different, you cannot load the parameters from one to create the other.

From the code you provided, it looks like the issue is coming from your `n_actions` parameter, that was set at 54 in the model you saved, but is now set at 41. The easiest correction would be to create a model with `n_actions=54` instead of 41.

More complicated options would be to train a new model from scratch with `n_actions=41`, or to only initialize the first 2 layers of the model and train it. In all cases, if you want a model with 41 classes as output, you will have some training to do.